# Dictionaries and spell-checking

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, language, dictionary, spellcheck

My default language is English, but I also sometimes type in Czech. I have added a Czech keyboard to OS X, and can switch between the two easily. The trouble is that OS X has no native Czech dictionary.

If I download Czech `.AFF` and `.DIC` files, I can place them inside `/Library/Spelling/`, but OS X does not switch which dictionary it uses for continuous spell-checking. I have "Automatic by Language" selected in the Keyboard preference pane, but this seems to work very sporadically, if at all.

Is there an easy solution here I am missing, or is this it? It seems odd that the keyboard and dictionary would not be linked, like they are in iOS. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a link to where you got the dictionary files from. Diky :)

Comment: @drevicko OpenOffice extensions repository (http://extensions.openoffice.org/) is a common source, see http://poedit.net/trac/wiki/Doc/SpellcheckerMac for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Only iOS links the keyboard and the spellcheck, OS X has never done that.  Most people find "automatic" unreliable.  To activate czech spellcheck, you should set the spell check to czech, either in system prefs/language & text/text/spelling or in Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar.  In Pages 4 and earlier and iBooks Author, you need to set Inspector > Text > More > Language.  MS Word and some other apps do their own thing.

The app Nisus Writer has preference settings that let you link keyboard and spellcheck dictionary.